# Laravel passing the data to route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm new in Laravel 5 and I need some help since I can't solve my simple problem.

I have a list of data on http://sample.com/partners and if I will click the link of the data I like it to redirect it to

http://sample.com/partners/users/77
and it will display the information about the user with the id 77.

I can't provide my route and controller but here is my partners.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $partners)
<tr bgcolor="#FF9999">
    <td><a href="{{ $partners->partner_id }}"> {{ $partners->partner_id }} </a></td>
    <td>{{$partners->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$partners->address}}</td>
    <td>{{$partners->tel_line_no}}</td>
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will update my post. About the question is I don't know what route should I put on my <a href=" "> tag and how to display the information of the users on the /partner/users/77 link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [url](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url) or [route](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route) helper functions in your `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="{{ url('partners/users', [$partners->partner_id]) }}">
    {{ $partners->partner_id }}
</a>
```

This assumes you have something like this in your `routes.php`:

```
Route::model('partner', App\Partner::class);
Route::get('/partners/users/{partner}', function(App\Partner $partner) {
    view('show-partner', ['partner' => $partner]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need this on your Routes.php:

```
Route::get('partnets/users/{users}','YourController@yourMethod');
```

Add this method to 'YourController' Controller:

```
Public function yourMethod($user)
{
 Your code... $user will have the ID
}
```

Your view:

```
<td><a href="{{ url('partners/users',[$partners->partner_id] }}"> {{ $partners->partner_id }} </a></td>
```

or

```
<td><a href="{{ action('YourController@yourMethod',['users' => $partners->partner_id] }}"> {{ $partners->partner_id }} </a></td>
```