# Laravel API url with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax to store the data. In that I need to send some dynamic data in URL.

For E.g:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "{{url('api/request/interview/{search_job}/request/users/{user_ids}')}}",
         method: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log('Result Sent',response);
            }
        });
```

In the above code, I dynamically send the data in `{search_job}` and `{user_ids}`. In that I'm getting an URL Error.

How can I send the values ?

Comment: Where is your error??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel passing the data to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622218/laravel-passing-the-data-to-route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this url type

```
url: "{{url('api/request/interview/{search_job}/request/users/{user_ids}')}}",
```

to

```
url: "{{url('')}}/api/request/interview/"+search_job+"/request/users/"+user_ids",
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define your data before call the ajax.

```
var search_job = job_data;
var user_id    = user_id_data;
```

Then, change the url to

```
'api/request/interview/'+search_job+'/request/users/'+user_ids+',
```

Here's the full code looks like:

```
var search_job = job_data;
var user_id    = user_id_data;

$.ajax({
    url      : 'api/request/interview/'+search_job+'/request/users/'+user_ids+',
    method   : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(response){
        console.log('Result Sent',response);
    }
});
```